# convert Html to Cshtml

Tags: html, razor

How do I convert this to cshtml with razor tags?

```
<head>

    <!-- Basic -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Modals | SHARED ON THEMELOCK.COM</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5 Admin Template" />
    <meta name="description" content="Porto Admin - Responsive HTML5 Template">
    <meta name="author" content="okler.net">

    <!-- Mobile Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <!-- Web Fonts  -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800|Shadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Vendor CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" />

    <!-- Specific Page Vendor CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/pnotify/pnotify.custom.css" />

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/theme.css" />

    <!-- Skin CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/skins/default.css" />

    <!-- Theme Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/theme-custom.css">

    <!-- Head Libs -->
    <script src="assets/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Looks like your question has more code. Can you give some more details about your question or can you post the CSHTML code which you have tried?

Comment: this actually is part of html template which i'm trying to port to cshtml

Answer (score 5):

Lets start a journey:

1. Open HTML document
2. Click CTRL+A
3. Click CTRL+C
4. Enter to your solution directory
5. Create new empty *.cshtml file
6. Click CTRL+V

That's all - it will be work. (In future add in tags what version of .Net are you using and what exactly need because my answer is correct to your question. For more information about Razor read [this](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c))

Comment: What about calling this new cshtml page? I think we still call it from Controller and there is no other way to keep it as html and call using href? Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new cshtml file. and paste your code